# Cannot FillColor in Google Maps Symbols (svg) marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Symbols as markers for my map. Specifically, I'm using the predefined *Circle* symbol.
However, the circle appear hollow from inside. *fillColor* is ignored but *strokeColor* works.

> Is it possible to fill the circle with color?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 4,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: colors[parseInt(idx)],
            strokeColor: colors[parseInt(idx)]
          },
          map: map

      });
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[The default value for fillOpacity is 0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol). So you should set it to 1:

```
fillOpacity: 1
```

Comment: Thankyou for the prompt answer!

Comment: Thank you for this! I was struggling to understand why the hell the fill color wasn't being set. I even tried to use a div instead of a SVG! Cheers!

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Comment: Huh, setting the opacity to 0 by default seems a bit silly to me. Fair enough, set the default fillColor to transparent, but setting the default opacity to 0 is just not intuitive.